# VISUALFORCE /APEX : Simple email feedback form

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I am developing a site in Visualforce and would like to offer user a simple form to send me feedback via email. There would be 3-4 fields like name, user's email, reason and feedback and "send" button. Clicking the send button should automatically send that message to my email address.

I do not want to store the form data in salesforce at least for now...All the stuff I found online about visualforce/apex and email is about saving that data to salesforce too.

Can I just make use of apex's email capabilities and send out email without storing that data anywhere in salesforce?

Thanks,
Calvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not required to insert/update/delete any records in the database when executing an action on a VisualForce page. You can leverage the [Outbound Email](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm) functionality to send out your notification. For something like this, you will probably want to familiarize yourself with the [SingleEmailMessage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) methods.

A simple example to get you going:

```
public PageReference actionSend() {
    String[] recipients = new String[]{'myemailaddress@somedomain.com'};
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(recipients.size());
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    msg.setToAddresses(recipients);
    msg.setSubject('Test Email Subject');
    msg.setHtmlBody('Test body including HTML markup');
    msg.setPlainTextBody('Test body excluding HTML markup');
    msg.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    msg.setUseSignature(false);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {msg}, false);
    return null;
}
```

If you are interested in sending these outbound messages from a dedicated email address (something like noreply@somecompany.com), you can set these up through the Setup -> Administration Setup -> Email Administration -> Organization-Wide Addresses menu. Once you have created an org-wide address, grab the Id from the URL and use the `setOrgWideEmailAddressId(Id)` method on your instance of `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.

Comment: Thank you..It looks like we can send this mail to multiple recipients by adding them in the recipients array. Am I right?

Comment: I am almost done making the form but did not see any way to change the "from" address. Do you know of a way we can change that? It is defaulting to the administrator of the customer portal/site which is myself.

Comment: I have updated my answer - you're looking for the `setOrgWideEmailAddressId` method.